# Error when trying to access Webform settings

Tags: 8, webforms

When I try to go to the Structure > Webforms > Settings and Webforms I am getting the following error. I tried the `$ drush webform-repair` command, but that doesn't work. My Drupal version is 8.6.4.

> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
>   TypeError: Argument 4 passed to
>   Drupal\webform\EntitySettings\WebformEntitySettingsBaseForm::appendBehaviors()
>   must be of the type array, null given, called in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ubci+webform/modules/webform/src/EntitySettings/WebformEntitySettingsGeneralForm.php
>   on line 274 in
>   Drupal\webform\EntitySettings\WebformEntitySettingsBaseForm->appendBehaviors()
>   (line 104 of
>   modules/webform/src/EntitySettings/WebformEntitySettingsBaseForm.php).

And I am getting another error when I try to download the results on Webforms > Download.

> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
>   Error: Unsupported operand types in
>   Drupal\webform\Form\WebformResultsExportForm->buildForm() (line 57 of
>   modules/webform/src/Form/WebformResultsExportForm.php).
>   Drupal\webform\Form\WebformResultsExportForm->buildForm(Array, Object,
>   Object)

Comment: In case you have not tried it: Goto Configuration/Development/Performance and clear the cache. Also since you are using Webform... be sure to use composer and see if the Webform and it's requirements are up to date.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution on the maintainer's blog: https://www.jrockowitz.com/blog/managing-webform-configuration. Go to `admin/structure/webform/config/advanced` and click 'Repair configuration'.

> #### Repairing admin configuration and webform settings
>
> If you happen upon some webform configuration that is outdated, you
>   can run the `drush webform:repair` command or click the 'Repair
>   configuration' via the admin UI under that 'Advanced' configuration
>   tab (`admin/structure/webform/config/advanced`)

Comment: this fixed the issue for me today

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was working on a migrated site and didn't have the `webform.settings` config.

To fix:

1. Grab config from an existing site: `/admin/config/development/configuration/single/export`
2. Import the config to current site: `/admin/config/development/configuration/single/import`

I had some errors about themes not being present, so I had to create dummy themes, install them, then uninstall them before the config import would work.